Deriving the CAPM pricing kernel from the general SDF and consumption-based kernel
I'm reading the paper "Quality minus junk" by Asness et al. (2019) and trying to understand the pricing kernel definition they provide on page 6. The authors present the following pricing kernel:
$$
\frac{M_{t+1}}{M_t} = \frac{1}{1+r^f} \left(1 + e^M_{t+1}\right)
$$
where $r^f$ is the risk-free rate and $e^M_{t+1}$ is the zero-mean innovation to the pricing kernel. They then state that if the Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM) holds, the pricing kernel is:
$$
e^M_{t+1} = -\lambda_t \left(\frac{r^{MKT}{t+1}-E_t(r^{MKT}{t+1})}{\sigma^2_t(r^{MKT}_{t+1})}\right)
$$
where $\lambda_t=E_t(r^{MKT}_{t+1})-r^f$ is the market risk premium.
I'm familiar with two other common forms of the pricing kernel:
The general stochastic discount factor (SDF) equation from asset pricing theory can be seen here:
Stochastic discount factor
The consumption-based pricing kernel from the consumption CAPM:
$$
m_{t+1} = \beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)}
$$
My question is: How can I derive the two euqations used in the paper from either the general SDF equation or the consumption-based pricing kernel? I'd appreciate a step-by-step explanation of the derivation process.
Additionally, I'm curious about the economic intuition behind the CAPM pricing kernel formula. How does it relate to the pricing kernel and to and to the basic CAPM model?
Please let me know if you need further context from the paper or have any other questions.
